# Checking private fields in unit testing

Tags: delphi, unit-testing

I have the following interface and class

```
interface
....
  MyInterface = interface
    ['{079729DE-3E8C-4C1B-80AD-114F0A4CD04A}']
    function MyFunction : integer;
    procedure MyProcedure;
  end;

  TMyClass = class (TInterfacedObject, MyInterface)
  private
    FMyValue : integer;
  public
    function MyFunction : integer;
    procedure MyProcedure;
  end;
```

---

```
implementation
.....
function TMyClass.MyFunction: integer;
var
  aResult : integer;
begin
  { here the value of AResult is changed}
  result := aResult;
end;

procedure TMyClass.MyProcedure;
var
  aValue : integer;
begin
  { here the value of FMyValue is changed}
  { here the value of aValue is changed}
end;
```

I can check the result of `MyFunction` easily with check (`MyFunction=...`) but I don't know how to check the values of `FMyValye` and `aValue` at the end of the procedure.

I'd rather avoid to add an extra function in both, interface and class, that retrieves the value of `FMyValue` and `aValue` because is used only for testing and not for production.

Comment: There is no need to check the private fields. The value doesn't matter if the public methods do what they should do and the class itself behave as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to check the value of private members and local variables. They are not part of the externally visible interface and so their values are of no concern.

If you are concerned about these values then your code architecture is incorrectly designed. The appropriate solution is of course to redesign the code.

Of course you could make the private field public, or return the local variable via an out parameter. But you don't want to do that, do you?

Comment: David, @Sir Rufo
Yes, the most important is the class behavior and the outcome of it but sometimes procedures accomplish several tasks and never return results as functions. My idea was to to test local variables in order to test each single tasks included in the procedure.

Comment: In order to make the design right, do you suggest to transform the procedure into a function and test the result returned by the same function ?

Comment: No. I suggest you don't attempt to test private unobservable things. Test the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to test `FMyValue` without adding a getter, you could make it protected rather than private.

In your test you could then add a derived class which could access this value, to let you check it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I should access FMyValue via TMyClass and not via MyInterface. If so, I would lose the benefit of dependency injection. How can I solve this ?

Comment: In your production code you continue to use your interface. In your tests when you want to test your implementations, you can manipulate `TMyClass` (or its derived class) directly, since it's what you want to test anyway